# Lotus notes many data over network when opening document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a number of databases on a Domino Server (version 8.5). On clients we open database which are on that server. If we open 1 document in the client then on the network we see that over 20+ mb is transported.

Is this normal when just opening documents? If the document has like 50 fields and an embedded view in it. Normally you would expect that the server will do all the actions an create the document and send it as small as possible to the client, but this does not seem to be the case.

I already enabled TCP compression. Any other tips to reduce the network load?

Comment: Does this happen to ANY document you open or just specific ones? Do you use XPages to show the document? Are there any big Images in the design of the form that is used to display the document? Did you do anything to prevent client to cache design?

Comment: Any document and we do not use xpages to show the document. There are no big images in the design of the form. We did not cache prevent client to cache design.

Comment: If you are opening it with the Notes client, it is not the case that "the server will do all the actions". All the formulas and scripts associated with the form will execute on the client. All the data those formulas and scripts require will be sent to the client. I'm not 100% sure what data associated with the embedded view is sent down, but that may also be a large amount of data in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, is it also possible to send maybe lesser data to the client and for example do some more actions on the server?

Comment: Sure you can. How you do it depends on what you are actually trying to do when the document is opened. Talk to the developer who created the database (or at least the form). If he/she is not available you may have to try to locate a developer. My email is in my profile if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

- Code in QueryOpen or PostOpen of the form, or subforms, especially code that loops through documents because it's the client that will be doing that work unless designed to run on the server.
- Computed-for-display fields that do lots of lookups.

Ideas I'm less sure about and might not actually have network issues:

- Use of private or 'shared, private on first use' views
- ?

Also, where are you measuring this? If you're measuring this at the server rather than the client, it's natural to wonder where your on-disk data is. Could it be that the notes database file is not literally inside your server?